# Is there a publication containing detailed cost and fuel usage functions for automobiles?

Tags: cost-functions

I want something that will take the elevation, fuel tank level, load/weight, road grade, etc and give me an instantaneous fuel burn value.

Comment: Have you checked with the Transport Research Board? They have a likely helpful handbook but I cannot find a copy online.

Comment: This does not seem to be an economics question?

Comment: @Giskard it is most indeed, its about compiled information regarding cost estimation and projection of a specifc applied nature. so yeah. it is. lol

Comment: @RegressForward I never heard of them :P but now I shall look them up.

Comment: @JohnSohn Seems like what you are actually looking for is a fuel burn rate, and then in the end you will want to multiply that with the current petrol price. You can easily find out the local petrol price (or historical oil prices), and the fuel burn rate is more about automobile engineering than economics.

Comment: @Giskard good cost functions are based off specifics.  and yes the fuel burn rate for a specific vehicle on a specific trip under specific circumstances that can be mostly modeled to make a cost benefit analysis or model related to various forms of engines and public transportation to determine energy product usage and possible negative externalities, with the fuel burn rate at its core specific to various models for comparison.

Comment: @Giskard so the need for this function expands into something a tad more complex than you are imagining.

Comment: @Giskard I'm actually more interested in effects on quantity demanded than I am a highly volatile often regionally varying nominal price